# Recognize the foreground application with a crossover application

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, electron

I am developping a crossplatform desktop application with angular2 and Electron.
I need to determine, at each moment, with this application, the foreground process which is running on the computer, whatever the OS (Windows, Linux, Mac).
I tried the  detect-active-title package on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-active-title) but it doesn't work. I have a "Platform not supported undefined" error.

So, at your opinion, what is the best solution for me to detect the foreground process, whatever if it is Linux, Mac or Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a module for that , Here is a module i used to spec a process uc usage , and it's fine for listing processes too https://github.com/branneman/current-processes.

https://github.com/octalmage/active-window
You can use this module to retrieve the active window name  it claims to be cross-platform

Hope it helps